# If a file is open get file to front

Tags: c#, excel

I get the following error when trying to open a workbook file.

`The process cannot access the file '.. File.xls' because it is being used by another process`.

Instead of opening the file again, if the file is already open, how do I bring that workbook forward.

---

*Copied from OP's comment:*

> Excel App is on front. The thing is, I opened a WorkBook programmatically, came to front. Now I did some work on old workbooks, clicked the button again to open the Workbook which is already open. Now since its open, gave me exception. So instead of that I want that old sheet to come front.

Comment: could you post the code you are using to open the workbook.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I am using Excel Interop.

Comment: What if the file is open, but not in Excel?

Comment: This question should not have been closed. It is a real question it is just badly worded.

Answer (score 3):

This is a two step solution

1. You have to first [find the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860656/how-does-one-figure-out-what-process-locked-a-file-using-c) that is currently using the file
2. Then, once you have the ProcessId, you have to [bring it to the front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987/bringing-window-to-the-front-in-c-using-win32-api) using the Win32 API

Answer (score 1):

If you are using excel-interop, then all you need to do is set visible to true for your instance of the excel application. For example

`excelApp.Visible = true;`

even if if the value is already true, this will bring it to the front.

Comment: Let me put the whole scenario: Excel App is on front. The thing is, I opened a WorkBook programmatically, came to front. Now I did some work on old workbooks, clicked the button again to open the Workbook which is already open. Now since its open, gave me exception. So instead of that I want that old sheet to come front.

Comment: @buffer so the app is on top, but you need to bring a worksheet to the front of the open application?

Comment: Yes. Thats what I am lokoing for. Excel is open. I want a particualr workbook to come on front.